# RStudio/R crashes when running script with data.table in Debian

Tags: r, data.table

While working in data.table I suddenly have crashes in while running a script that did not have problems before. The script runs in Windows, but crashes in my Linux Xubuntu 64 bit machine. I cannot reproduce the error.

The message I get is :

```
Error in mult %chin% c("first", "last", "all") : 
Internal error: savetl_init checks failed (0 100 0x50a6b90 0x82141d0). 
Please report to datatable-help.
```

The crash occurs at the moment when I try to set a key:

```
setkey(vars,parameter)
```

but earlier the crash occurred at different places - I can't localize it.

Other crash message I have seen occurring:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f5ffecdcd50, pid=6368, tid=140050620934144

JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_51) (build 1.7.0_51-b00)
Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  [datatable.so+0x12d50]  cradix_r+0x60

Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. 
To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
```

When running in R [so not in RStudio] I get:

```
*** caught segfault ***
address 0xffffffffb3e13480, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
1: forder(x, cols, sort = TRUE, retGrp = FALSE)
2: setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose)
3: setkey(vars, parameter)
4: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
5: eval(ei, envir)
6: withVisible(eval(ei, envir))
7: source("check_dt3.R")

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
```

Does anybody know what is happening here? [the only things I can think of are switching to Sun Java, re-installing RStudio, re-installing R].

Comment: Do you get the same problem running your Rscript on linux outside Rstudio ?

Comment: You seem to be using the development version of data.table. There have been quite some active (internal) changes recently. There were a couple of `forder` related bugs quashed yesterday - related to `cradix` (by Matt). So, it could be because of that (not sure), you should try updating it. If you still experience this issue, you should file it as a bug (and it'd be great if you could get a reproducible example). In short, first try updating again.

Comment: @statquant -> yes, it also crashes under R [but I get a different message, see question].

Comment: @Arun -> I have installed data.table 1.8.10 and indeed that solves the problem. I am dependent on 1.8.11 though since that can cast large tables [reshape2 crashes]. The only pattern I can find are the special signs in the character string [Swedish and German names for example]. I can lead the ggplot2:diamonds set through the same script under 1.8.11 without problems.

Comment: Henk, the problem you mention has been fixed IIRC. You should try upgrading to the latest devel version (install 1.8.11 again) and that should not result in segfault. Could you please verify this? Thank you.

Comment: Please update to the latest commit of v1.8.11 (1146 currently). I suspect that'll fix it given your last comment. Please also state the version number in your question (by chance we can tell it's v1.8.11 in this case because of the output). We are seeing if we can get the commit number into the startup banner as well. Also, some people and maybe S.O. mods would prefer S.O. not to be used for bug reporting (and a crash is always a bug). It's debatable but in this case, since it's the development version as well, an email to us directly, or datatable-help would save the tag getting clogged.

Comment: BTW: you are in linux so "reinstalling" R/RStudio (which is a Windows reflex) is unlikely to be of any help.

Comment: @Arun - I have downloaded and installed 1.8.11 again, and I get a different error now, but no total R crash. Will email the output [error and traceback]. Thanks for your support...!

Comment: @Arun - bug report submitted [#5368].

Comment: Relevant github issue: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/20

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer and open qestion.
Issue has been reported [#20](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/20) and resolved on the same day.
The question is irrelevant for 1.9.2+ versions of data.table.

Comment: Just checked the R-Forge report. It seems to have been due to some error in installation. Reinstalling fixed it.